# Normal sentences

Tags: code-golf, math, string

Write a program or function which, given an input string and a standard deviation `σ`, outputs that string along the normal distribution curve with mean `0` and standard deviation `σ`.

#### Normal distribution curve

The `y` coordinate of each character `c` is:

[image]

where `σ` is given as input, and where `x` is the `x` axis coordinate of `c`.

- The character in the center of the string has `x = 0`. If the string's length is even, either of the two middle characters can be chosen as the center.
- Characters are separated by steps of `0.1` (e.g. the character to the left of the center one has `x = -0.1`, the one to the right of the middle one has `x = 0.1`, etc.).

#### Printing the string

- Lines, like characters, are separated by steps of `0.1`.
- Each character is printed on the line with the `y` value that is closest to its own `y` value (if the value is precisely in between the values of two lines, choose the one with the biggest value (just like how `round` usually returns `1.0` for `0.5`)).
- For example, if the `y` coordinate of the center value (i.e. the maximum value) is `0.78` and the `y` coordinate of the first character is `0.2`, then there will 9 lines: the center character being printed on line `0` and the first character being printed on line `8`.

#### Inputs and outputs

- You may take both inputs (the string and `σ`) as program arguments, through `STDIN`, function arguments or anything similar in your language.
- The string will only contain printable `ASCII` characters. The string can be empty.
- `σ > 0`.
- You may print the output to `STDOUT`, in a file, or return it from a function (**as long as** it is a string and not say a list of strings for each line).
- A trailing new line is acceptable.
- Trailing spaces are acceptable as long as they don't make the line exceed the last line in length (so no trailing space is acceptable on the last line).

#### Test cases

```
σ    String

0.5  Hello, World!

     , W     
   lo   or   
  l       l  
 e         d 
H           !



0.5  This is a perfectly normal sentence

                tly                
              ec    n              
             f       o             
            r         r            
           e           m           
          p             a          
        a                l         
      s                    se      
This i                       ntence



1.5  Programming Puzzles & Code Golf is a question and answer site for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers.

                                                d answer site for p                                               
                                      uestion an                   rogramming                                     
                      Code Golf is a q                                        puzzle enthusia                     
Programming Puzzles &                                                                        sts and code golfers.



0.3  .....................

          .          
         . .         

        .   .        

       .     .       


      .       .      

     .         .     
    .           .    
   .             .   
...               ...
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf),

```
                 nsw                 
                a   er               
              t                      
             s         i             
            e           n            
           t                         
         or               by         
       sh                   te       
so the                        s wins.
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69350/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53833/8478)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/74552/text-on-a-circle?rq=1).

Comment: I think the last test case should have 3 dots in the top row, not 1.

Comment: @addison I don't have my reference implementation on this computer but I don't know why Mego get's a different result. The result he obtains with his code seems very "blocky". Ignore that test case for the moment I guess.

Comment: @Fatalize I think I see the discrepancy - my solution isn't printing out the blank lines. I'll work on fixing that after I get a byte to eat.

Comment: Is only one trailing newline acceptable, or can there be multiples?

Comment: @Mego Only one is acceptable.

Comment: @Fatalize I have just realised that my [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84976/55526) is not rounding in exactly the way that you specify (i.e. up for `x.x5`). Both SciPy's [around](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) (which I am using) and Python's builtin [round](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#round) use [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), not round half up. Is this OK?

Comment: @TheBikingViking I'll let that pass, that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python 3 with [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/index.html), <s>239</s> 233 bytes

```
from scipy import stats,around,arange
def f(s,t):
 l=len(t);p=[];y=around(stats.norm.pdf((arange(l)-l//2)*.1,scale=s),1)*10
 for i in range(l):p+=[[' ']*(max(y)-y[i])];p[i]+=[t[i]]+[' ']*(y[i]-y[0])
 for j in zip(*p):print(*j,sep='')
```

A function that takes input via argument of standard deviation `s` and string `t`, and prints the result to STDOUT.

**How it works**

```
from scipy import stats,around,arange  Import the statistics, rounding and range functions
                                       from SciPy
def f(s,t):                            Function with input standard deviation s and string
                                       t
l=len(t);p=[]                          Define the much-used length of t as l and initialise
                                       the print values list p
arange(l)                              Generate a list of integer x values in [0,l)...
...-l//2*.1                            ...and scale such that 0 is at the middle character
                                       and the x-step is 0.1
stats.norm.pdf(...,scale=s)            Generate a list containing the y values for each x
                                       value by calling the normal probability
                                       density function scaled with s...
y=around(...,1)                        ...round all values to 1 decimal place...
...*10                                 ...and multiply by 10 to give the vertical index of
                                       each character
for i in range(l):...                  For all characters in t...
p+=[[' ']*(max(y)-y[i])]               ..add the number of lines below the character as
                                       spaces...
p[i]+=[t[i]]+[' ']*(y[i]-y[0])         ...add the character and the number of lines above
                                       the character as spaces

This leaves p containing a list for each desired output line, but transposed.

for j in zip(*p):...                   For every output line in the transpose of p...
print(*j,sep='')                       ...print the output line
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/LzrOpE)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby: <s>273</s> 254 Bytes

```
->n,s{j,o,g,r,l=-(n.size/2),[],0,{}
n.gsub(/./){(r[((2*Math::PI)**-0.5*10*Math.exp(-(j/1e1)**2/2/s/s)/s).round]||="")<<$&
j+=1}
r.sort.map{|y, c|o<<(l ?$/*(y-l-1):"")+(" "*g)+(c[0,(h=c.size)/2])+(" "*(n.size-g*2-h))+(c[h/2,h])
g+=h/2
l=y}
puts o.reverse}
```

A huge thanks to [Kevin Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/kevin-lau-not-kenny) for saving 18 bytes!

Comment: Lambdas don't need parens: `->n,s{...` is fine. You don't need brackets when assigning multiple variables: `o,g,r,l=[],0,{}` works just fine. `$/` can be used in place of `?\n`. Order of operations means you don't have to put all your multiplies on line 5 in parens. `puts` automatically unfolds arrays and separates them with newlines when printing. `n.gsub(/./){...` beats out `n.each_char{...` by a bit because you can take out the `|c|` and put `$&` where any mention of `c` was. Make your hash values strings (start with `||=""` not `||=[]`) and you can change `c[...]*""` to `c[...]`